# What should be the right way to pass the protected attribute in aif360.sklearn.metrics import disparate_impact_ratio?

Tags: python, aif360

I am trying to compute the disparate_impact_ratio in the Adult Dataset. Currently I wrote this : disparate_impact_ratio(uci_adult_df['income'],prot_attr='sex',priv_group=1, pos_label=1,sample_weight=None)

It is giving me the error
ValueError: Some of the attributes provided are not present in the dataset. Expected a subset of:
[]
Got:
[0 0 0 ... 1 0 1]

What should be the right way to pass the prot_attr='sex'?
Currently sex is an array =[0,1,1,0]